# Selenium Web Driver | Find object | Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In advance I apologize for my English, because I write with an interpreter.

There is a task to click on one of these accounts, suppose AAccount, using Selenium Web Driver (Python, Chrome).
The problem is that it's impossible to do this on XPath and CSS, because the elements are the same.
Here is part of the source code for the page. I also attached a screenshot of the page.

[image]

```html
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="gb_ag" ng-non-bindable="" id="gb"><div class="gb_hf gb_fg"><div class="gb_ib gb_fg gb_R gb_eg"><div class="gb_7d gb_R gb_fg gb_7f"><div class="gb_Q gb_R gb_S gb_fg"><span class="gb_P gb_R">TeAOK</span></div></div><div class="gb_sc gb_fg gb_R"><div class="gb_ga" id="gbsfw" style="background-color:#eee;min-width:376px"></div><div class="gb_Ac gb_Wc gb_R gb_Bc"><div class="gb_Dc"><a class="gb_b" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="gb_Ec gb_Fc gb_4b"></div></a><div class="gb_lb"></div><div class="gb_kb" style="border-bottom-color:#eee"></div></div><div class="gb_ga" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="assertive"></div></div><div class="gb_fb gb_Wc gb_fg gb_R"><div class="gb_Dc gb_hb gb_fg gb_R"><a class="gb_b gb_db gb_R" href="https://accounts.google.com/SignOutOptions?hl=ru&amp;continue=https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DelegateAccountSelector%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.google.com%252Fo%252Foauth2%252Fauth%253Fclient_id%253D702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com%2526redirect_uri%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fvkmix.com%252Fmodules%252Fyoutube%252Fbot2.php%2526scope%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fyoutube%2526response_type%253Dcode%2526access_type%253Doffline" title="Аккаунт Google: TeAOK G9T3arz  &#10;(teaokg9t3arz@gmail.com)" role="button" tabindex="0"><span class="gb_8a gbii"></span></a><div class="gb_lb"></div><div class="gb_kb"></div></div><div class="gb_mb gb_ga" aria-label="Информация об аккаунте" aria-hidden="true"><div class="gb_pb"><a class="gb_qb gb_tf gb_sb" aria-label="Изменить картинку профиля" href="https://profiles.google.com/?hl=ru"><div class="gb_tb gbip" title="Профиль"></div><span class="gb_jb">Изменить</span></a><div class="gb_rb"><div class="gb_ub gb_vb">TeAOK G9T3arz</div><div class="gb_wb">teaokg9t3arz@gmail.com</div><div class="gb_ob"><a href="https://myaccount.google.com/privacypolicy">Конфиденциальность</a></div><a class="gb_Fa gb_qf gbp1 gb_xb" href="https://myaccount.google.com/?utm_source=OGB&amp;utm_medium=act">Мой аккаунт</a></div></div><div class="gb_Cb"><div class="gb_Db gb_6a" aria-hidden="true"><a class="gb_Eb gb_Mb" href="/b/0/DelegateAccountSelector?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Fauth%3Fclient_id%3D702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php%26scope%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube%26response_type%3Dcode%26access_type%3Doffline&amp;authuser=0"><img class="gb_Ob gb_sb" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" alt="Профиль" data-src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Yg4816hNGF4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAyYBF6hOAK-q02pBDqts2Bde8yxxNX1wQ/s48-c-mo/photo.jpg"><div class="gb_Hb"><div class="gb_Pb">TeAOK G9T3arz</div><div class="gb_Qb">teaokg9t3arz@gmail.com (по умолчанию)</div></div></a></div><a class="gb_Sb gb_6a" href="https://myaccount.google.com/brandaccounts?authuser=0&amp;continue=https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DelegateAccountSelector%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.google.com%252Fo%252Foauth2%252Fauth%253Fclient_id%253D702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com%2526redirect_uri%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fvkmix.com%252Fmodules%252Fyoutube%252Fbot2.php%2526scope%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fyoutube%2526response_type%253Dcode%2526access_type%253Doffline&amp;service=/b/0/DelegateAccountSelector%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.google.com%252Fo%252Foauth2%252Fauth%253Fclient_id%253D702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com%2526redirect_uri%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fvkmix.com%252Fmodules%252Fyoutube%252Fbot2.php%2526scope%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fyoutube%2526response_type%253Dcode%2526access_type%253Doffline%26authuser%3D%24authuser" aria-hidden="true"><span class="gb_Tb gb_4b"></span><div class="gb_Ub">Все аккаунты брендов &raquo;</div></a></div><div class="gb_yb"><div><a class="gb_Fa gb_pf gb_xb" href="https://accounts.google.com/AddSession?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fb%2F0%2FDelegateAccountSelector%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.google.com%252Fo%252Foauth2%252Fauth%253Fclient_id%253D702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com%2526redirect_uri%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fvkmix.com%252Fmodules%252Fyoutube%252Fbot2.php%2526scope%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fyoutube%2526response_type%253Dcode%2526access_type%253Doffline">Добавить аккаунт</a></div><div><a class="gb_Fa gb_rf gb_yf gb_xb" id="gb_71" href="https://accounts.google.com/Logout" target="_top">Выйти</a></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="gb_Zb gb_R gb_3b" id="gbq1" style="max-width:152px;min-width:152px"><div class="gb_0b"><a class="gb_3d gb_2b" href="/" title="Мой аккаунт" data-ved="0EMQuCAQ"><span class="gb_Za gb_4b"></span></a></div></div></div><div id="gbw"></div></div><div class="gb_sd" id="gba"></div>
  <div class="delegate-account-selector main content clearfix">
  <div class="sign-in">
  <div class="signin-box">
  <h2 id="signin-action">Выберите аккаунт</h2>
  <ol class="accounts" id="account-list">
  <li id="account-teaokg9t3arz@gmail.com">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=none">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-0"></span>
  <span class="account-name">TeAOK G9T3arz</span>
  <span class="account-email" id="account-email-0">teaokg9t3arz@gmail.com</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-0">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="account-">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=105773503169388790046">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-1"></span>
  <span class="account-name">EAccount</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-1">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="account-">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=116942572818460775716">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-2"></span>
  <span class="account-name">FAccount</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-2">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="account-">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=110025695516281123129">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-3"></span>
  <span class="account-name">GAccount</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-3">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="account-">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=100327913140968503320">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-4"></span>
  <span class="account-name">CAccount</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-4">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="account-">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=114686295257876098243">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-5"></span>
  <span class="account-name">DAccount</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-5">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="account-">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=101169419531313874972">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-6"></span>
  <span class="account-name">iAccount</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-6">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="account-">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=116191438938972075200">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-7"></span>
  <span class="account-name">AAccount</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-7">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="account-">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=106861284959818641724">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-8"></span>
  <span class="account-name">BAccount</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-8">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="account-">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=104823728391082992328">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-9"></span>
  <span class="account-name">IAccount</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-9">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="account-">
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=702580890038-5fs7raaanbrl7rssnkg3e62qgprukbni.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvkmix.com%2Fmodules%2Fyoutube%2Fbot2.php&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&amp;response_type=code&amp;access_type=offline&amp;pageId=102918689899435112584">
  <span class="account-image" id="account-image-10"></span>
  <span class="account-name">JAccount</span>
  <span class="select-account text-icon-select" id="account-account-10">Выберите</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  </ol>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-content">
  <div class="product-headers">
  <h1 class="redtext">Аккаунты</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="select-account">
  <p>
  Выберите аккаунт Google
  </p>
  <ul>
  <li>
  TeAOK G9T3arz
  (teaokg9t3arz@gmail.com)
  </li>
  <li>
  EAccount
  </li>
  <li>
  FAccount
  </li>
  <li>
  GAccount
  </li>
  <li>
  CAccount
  </li>
  <li>
  DAccount
  </li>
  <li>
  iAccount
  </li>
  <li>
  AAccount
  </li>
  <li>
  BAccount
  </li>
  <li>
  IAccount
  </li>
  <li>
  JAccount
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="google-footer-bar">
  <div class="footer content clearfix">
  <ul id="footer-list">
  <li>Google</li>
  <li>
  <a  href="https://accounts.google.com/TOS?loc=RU&hl=ru" >Конфиденциальность и условия</a>
  </li>
  <li id="footer-help"><a  href="https://support.google.com/accounts?hl=ru" >Справка</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Share code you've tried

Comment: Damn, there was a lot of options, but i delete it.
XPath and CSS - they did not work because all accounts had the same elements.
The ID /tag/name  could not find the item. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to locate required element [by partial link text](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_partial_link_text):

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("AAccount").click()
```

If it doesn't work, you can try to add some time to wait for required element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "AAccount"))).click()
```

Comment: I tried it, but it did not help.
Issued an error about the fact that this object was not found.

Comment: Then try `XPath` `//a[contains(., "AAccount")]
`. Same result?

Comment: Kk, i try it now, and write about result. Можем говорить на русском?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145821/selenium-web-driver-find-object-python

Comment: Dont have 20 rep.

Comment: Well, I'll try it tomorrow, then I'll mark the answer right. And if something is not so write in the comments. Thank you)

Comment: Can you give your VK/Telegram? In the chat.

Comment: Sorry, I have no accounts in these services)

Comment: Ok) Then tomorrow I will write in the comments. And so, thanks for the help)